# How to speed up operations on a python array?

Tags: python, performance, loops, numpy

I have an 1D numpy array `A` of shape (N by 1) where N=4000000. I need to run a function (fcn) on each of its elements.

```
import bumpy as np
def fcn(a, B, c):
    return a - np.sqrt(c) * B) / np.sqrt(1 - c)
```

Since B is (M=100 by P=20) and c is scalar, the output of the function is an array of size M by P.

I have tried different methods, but all are slow for example:

```
for a in A:
    result = fcn(a, B, c)
    # do something with result...
```

Do you know how to speed it up, for example by multiprocessing or any other way?

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis

Comment: And what is `bumpy`?

Comment: For a scalar `c`, `math.sqrt(c)` is faster.

Comment: If you want a (N,M,P) result, `A[:,None,None]` can be used instead of `a`

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory, the easiest is what @hpaulj suggest:

```
for result in (A[:,None,None] - np.sqrt(c) * B) / np.sqrt(1 - c):
    # do stuff
```

If you are short on memory, at least precompute what you can:

```
X = 1 / np.sqrt(1 - c)
Y = np.sqrt(c) * B / np.sqrt(1 - c)
for a in A:
    result = a * X - Y
    # do stuff
```